# How to solve Missing required parameter for [Route: classes.destroy][URI: classes/{class}] [Missing parameter: class] (did this with laravel)

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-8

ClassController(destroy function)

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        $classes = $this->classesRepository->find($id);
        if (empty($classes)) {
            return redirect(route('classes.index'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: may be you are not passing your parameter. can you add your frontend code from where you calling these route ?

Comment: the code is below

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem by simply editing my database table

example(you will get this error if you use)

```
Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('classes_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the code below solves your problem

```
Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Or you can simply move to each page and change (model ,controller, http pages) in oder to change $id to $class_id